# Why is 'this' itself undefined in function scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super()
    //this.buttonOneClick = this.buttonOneClick.bind(this);
  }

  buttonOneClick() {
    const { setTestData } = this.props;

    setTestData("test");
  }

  render() {
    const { testData } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Test App</h1>
        <div>{testData}</div>
        <button onClick={this.buttonOneClick}>Test</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The component App is exported with react-redux's connect method to map the `setTestData`-function to the props (thats where `setTestData` is coming from).

When I set the `buttonOneClick()` handler without biding the component context to it (see the outcommented line in my code in `constructor()`) I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I understand that props wouldn't be defined since the handler is executed in the global context which doesn't know about props but how I understand the error it implies that `this` itself is not defined which doesn't make sense to me. Why is this the case? Shouldn't `this` always be defined in any execution context?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't this always be defined in any execution context?

No.

There is no implicit `this` value in strict mode.

```js
"use strict";

function example() {
    alert(this);
}

example();
```

Comment: IMHO it worth mentioning that class bodies enforce strict mode.

Comment: Good to know. I'll read more about strict mode now (do I get it right that ´this´ is only undefined in strict mode as long as it would refer to the global context?)

Answer (score -1):

We’re getting an error because **this** is not defined when onClick calls our buttonOneClick() function.

Usually, you would fix this by binding **this** to the buttonOneClick function so it always stays the same. So we have to bind that in the constructor.

```
this.buttonOneClick = this.buttonOneClick.bind(this);
```

Possible work-around if you don't want to use the binding and all is to use the es2015 javascript arrow functions

```
buttonOneClick = () => console.log(this.props);
```

An arrow function does not have its own **this** so it will use **this** off its context, which is our Component. This is called **Lexical Scoping**

Comment: Also the question is not about how to uncomment the line of code but about how `this` got `undefined`.

Comment: Updated the answer @YuryTarabanko

Comment: @B001ᛦ I misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer